# Blender's Render mode displays walls as invisible; opaque in Solid & Wireframe Modes

Tags: blender, blender-2.67

I have a model designed in Blender of a spaceship hallway. In all modes except for Render it appears as designed. However when I switch to Render mode the walls vanish.

Wireframe view:
[image: Wireframe View]

Solid view:
[image: Solid View]

Rendered View:
[image: Rendered View]

More unusual, when I rotate the image while in Rendered mode, I can see the walls but only if they are exactly between the camera and the rear of the object. It's hard to explain, but I uploaded a short video of the phenomenon: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YIuppScj9g

I'm uncertain what I did to cause the render mode to appear so incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was being caused by the Bevel modifier. Removing it caused the Render mode to display properly. Possibly a bug, but that fixed the issue.